# Does Windows 10 IoT support Java on the Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, java, windows-iot

A preliminary web search seems to indicate that the answer is currently no.

Does anyone know about plans to support java on Win 10 IoT?

Comment: If you would like to develop in Java, get something that can run Android.

Comment: I've removed the long diatribe from your question that I presume was a response to @ppumkin's comment, because it seriously detracted from your question, which is legitimate (why wouldn't windows support java?).  If you want to respond to a comment, generally respond with a comment unless it requires adding *relevant* material to the question.  If anyone's upset by this, etc., feel free to ping `@goldilocks` in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery), we can try to get everyone together and slug it out properly ;)

Comment: Really this question is backwards -- the issue is whether java supports windows IoT.   MS doesn't do anything to "support" it anywhere; Oracle does.  It's up to them to create a port.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is indeed "Nope". 
Microsoft Windows is a bit more "closed off" so I wouldn't sit around and wait for Java to come to IoT any time soon. If you want Java, go with a [Linux distro](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) like Raspbian.

**Regarding your added note:**

In the same analogy, you are coming to a swimming pool asking if you could surf here, because you were a surfer for 15 years somewhere in the Pacific.
Yes it's a shame you can't surf in this swimming pool, but if you really want to surf in a pool, maybe look at ***an Intel Compute Stick***.

Comment: And I am pretty happy that it cant run Java, Flash or any other rubbish. Well, you make can Python apps, Node.JS, and other in VS2015 for IoT. But C# is like Java offshoot and has XAML editor, full OpenGL support, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Two years passed and Azul systems (as I understand not without the help from Microsoft) developed Java for Win 10 Iot

http://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-embedded/

Not much is known about the performance/stability yet.

Comment: Thank you for the news. According to that link they provide it for the MinnowBoard, not Raspberry Pi. But good to see some development.

Comment: Indirectly Azul states that it should work on Rasperry PI. In terms of Azul and Raspberry being on the same page)) https://www.azul.com/microsoft-and-azul-systems-partner-to-bring-zulu-embedded-to-windows-iot/

Answer (score 0):

Windows want to push C# because it's their personal language, but yea, if you want java just go with some linux distro. (Raspbian for instance.)

Comment: They indeed only want to use C# - But you do have a choice of making apps in Python also, or Node.JS and others. Its basically packaded into a universal app that will run on any Windows 10, desktop, mobile, IoT - With limitations obviosly, you cant use GPIO on Windows Phone, but generally speaking the CORE API is all the same. Java, its good there is no support because its grown into a monster SDK, and slow, just look at Android... but... there may be support one day, just no official way at this very point in time

Comment: @ppumkin Java is generally faster than python.  Windows doesn't have to support it anymore than linux does, but there's no need to make an excuse: *the reason would be no one has compiled one*.  A third party (e.g. Oracle) *could* create a java for windows 10 ARM (and I guess, might eventually), but they have not.  That's the reason it's not there.   Not some strategy by Microsoft.

Comment: In fact, looking at [this](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/csharp.php), it seems C# isn't  really faster than Java -- which is about what I would have guessed.

Comment: It is .NET 5 strategy!! There is no more VB support. There is no more WebForms (classic) support, they targeting Mono. I didn't say they anti Java... .NET5/ IoT /Win10 and Universal Apps is only around several months! Not like Unix which is around 30ish years! There may be likely be Java Support,as you say, just needs to be compiled. By mentioning Python, I negated the fact of its their strategy to NOT support Java.. They want to Support a TON of stuff! To run everywhere.. be written by anyone.. Just on Win10.. :) Gotta accept that.

Comment: I dont know about that comparison thing. C# is is the same family as Java, which is the same family as C++ - Some things are faster, others are not. Developing in C# and VS is much faster than in Java. I have been there, tried it all and I prefer MS dev, as it is NOW, Years ago it was shocking.

Comment: If they want to attract people to the platform I am sure java is in the pipe, because they are going to cut out *a very large number* of developers otherwise.  Oh BTW here's a [benchmark done on windows](http://reverseblade.blogspot.fi/2009/02/c-versus-c-versus-java-performance.html) showing a trivial difference in performance.   If you knew this it was odd to say the reason is because it is "slow".    It looks to me like the LOC from the benchmarks game is in java's favor if anything -- development speed is in the mind of the beholder, lol.

Comment: That said, I dunno why anyone doing serious embedded work uses anything involving bytecode, or anything that isn't purely compiled to machine code.  There's my prejudice.  But I don't do serious embedded work...I just tool around.

Comment: Yea.. its really difficult to benchmark these things now a days.Usually one only benchmarks when there is a specific bottleneck, comparison by Language is pretty much non constructive. It would be nice to have Java on IoT. Although, I have seen Java as APP's loosing traction in the last 7 years. Even when I see a Java plugin on a website, that is pretty rare find now a days. I heard all the server side stuff is pretty decent, some great high availability stuff. Either way... interesting times. The only loosers here is Apple in the whole thing... but that's another story.